# I can't install window games I get an error writing resource (6)

Tags: 16.04

I am new to Ubuntu and love to play games that are Windows-based. How can I install them on Ubuntu?

Comment: When do you get this error message? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: Some Windows games/software can run emulated with Wine but not all What are you trying to install and how?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to install games that are based on Windows, you should check the developer's or game's website to check whether the game is available on Linux. If yes, then you can install it according to the method listed on the website. Keep in mind that Windows WIN32 executables (EXE files) cannot be run on Linux.